# Breaking down data into groups

Tags: sql-server

I have the code

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.census.Group_Code, dbo.census.Gender, SUM(dbo.v_Courses.Dur_In_Hours) 
                      AS SumOf_Dur_In_Hours
FROM         dbo.v_Courses INNER JOIN
                      dbo.census ON dbo.v_Courses.Job_Group_Code = dbo.census.Group_Code
WHERE     (dbo.v_Courses.System = 'GEMS') AND (NOT (dbo.v_Courses.Course_ID LIKE 'UPS%')) AND 
                      (dbo.v_Courses.First_Access_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 
                      102))
GROUP BY dbo.census.Group_Code, dbo.census.Gender
ORDER BY dbo.census.Group_Code
```

Its purpose to give me the total hours of my job level and gender, but the job levels are all returning the same number of hours for each gender. And I cannot figure out how to get them to separate.

SO the results look liket this, but there is no way each gender has the same number of hours.

```
Job     Gen         Hours
11  F   10886.50417
11  M   10886.50417
16  F   33494.17222
16  M   33494.17222
16  U   33494.17222
21  F   19267.76361
21  M   19267.76361
```

It is the Gender that is causing the duplicates

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  `TOP` is not syntax in MySQL.

Comment: Are you sure that's MySQL? I don't think it supports the `TOP` keyword.

Comment: SQL Server is what I am using

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Can you post some data for each table and the table structure?

Comment: Since you figured out that it is the `gender` causing, is this resolved?  If not, then post some data for each table and the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you include gender on inner join?
or v_courses dont have this field?

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.census.Group_Code, dbo.census.Gender, SUM(dbo.v_Courses.Dur_In_Hours) 
                  AS SumOf_Dur_In_Hours
FROM         dbo.v_Courses 
INNER JOIN dbo.census 
   ON dbo.v_Courses.Job_Group_Code = dbo.census.Group_Code
   AND dbo.v_Courses.Gender = dbo.census.Gender
WHERE     (dbo.v_Courses.System = 'GEMS') AND (NOT (dbo.v_Courses.Course_ID LIKE 'UPS%')) AND 
                  (dbo.v_Courses.First_Access_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 
                  102))
GROUP BY dbo.census.Group_Code, dbo.census.Gender
ORDER BY dbo.census.Group_Code
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the query without the group do you see duplicate lines? If so you probably need another restriction in the join/where.

Comment: When I run it without the group no there are no duplicates, what kind of john do you suggest

Comment: I think then we'd need to see a table structure and or sample data to help more.

Comment: Actually its the Gender that is causing the duplicates

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to link the GENDER fields in both tables. Thank you all for your help though.